# Removing the effects of a tag using CSS

Tags: html, css

My Drupal theme generates:

```
<div class="field1">
  Field 1
</div>
<div class="field2">
  <h3>Field 2</h3>
</div>
```

The results is that `Field 2` has another style.

How can I remove the effects of `h3` using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way - remove h3 tag. But sometimes, when you need to reset all styles of parent element - use global attributes, like "font" for "font-size", "font-style" and so on...
Warning of inheriting paddings, margins borders and background styles - this can be look ugly. For example, when your element has padding and border wiil duplicates for each element:)

```
.someclass * {
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;

    /* optional reset */
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/q72EM/

Answer (score 1):

you can access the h3 as follows:

```
.field2 h3{ //style here }
```

This will change the style of any h3 inside an element with a class of field2. If you want to be extra specific:

```
div.field2 > h3 { //style here }
```

This will only change the style of an h3 element that is a first level descendant of a div with a class of field2. I would recommend you look into css selectors.

To remove any existing effects, you would have to overwrite them. This can be done by just setting the values back to the default for the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can only "remove" the effects by setting properties to whatever value they had before the styles for `<h3>` get applied. For example you can reset the font size with

```
.field > h3 {
    font-size: medium;
}
```

You will need to do this for all properties that get modified by your CSS or the browser's internal stylesheet, but there's help to be had: modern development tools (e.g. Chrome's) will allow you to inspect an element and show you what properties it has and where they came from (so you can see that `font-size` has been modified). Looking at the appropriate CSS standards will show you what the default value is for each of these properties (e.g. `font-size` is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-size-props)).

Answer (score 0):

Used to this

as like this

```
.field2 h3{
color:black;
font-size:20px;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

you can easily edit like this :-

**CSS**

```
.field2 h3 {
color:red;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/hZvu2RIk)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the effects of tags in CSS, except by writing CSS code that overrides stylistic settings that elements have due to browser defaults or other settings.

For an `h3` element, the properties that are probably set in browser default style sheets are `display`, `unicode-bidi`, `font-size`, `font-weight`, `margin`, and `page-break-after`. (Cf. to Appendix D of the CSS 2.1 spec, [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html).) You can set these to the desired values, and even a simple selector will suffice, e.g.

```
h3 { font-size: 120%; font-weight: normal; margin: 0; }
```

However, other style sheets that affect your document may have other settings on `h3`. And there is really no law against browser default style sheets using e.g. colors for headings or setting a specific font family.

To override other CSS settings in general, you need to use CSS rules with a sufficiently specific selector.